# How to display a HTMLElement from a variable in an Angular component?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I store a dynamically generated `HTMLElement` in a variable in my component class. I would like to display it, but I have no idea how is that possible. I tried it like this:

Inside the component class:

```
elem: HTMLElement;
```

In the template:

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="elem"></ng-container>
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: templateRef.createEmbeddedView is not a function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a naked `HTMLElement`, there's nothing Angular-y you can do. `NgTemplateOutlet` expected a `TemplateRef`, not a vanila `HTMLElement` object.

To insert an HTML Element into the DOM, simply use the appropriate DOM method for that. Which one you'll use entirely depends on the place where you want to use it.

For example, you could do

```
const wrapper = document.querySelector('div.wrapper')
wrapper.append(el) // pass in your element
```

You can also grab the reference to the wrapper in a more Angular way, by adding an Angular reference in the template on the element you want to select,

```
<div class="wrapper" #wrapper></div>
```

and using `ViewChild` decorator on a property where you want Angular to assign the `ElementRef` to.

```
@ViewChild('wrapper', { static: true, read: ElementRef })
public wrapperElRef: ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>
```

Once the view is initialized (you'll be notified when this happens via the `ngAfterViewInit` hook), you can grab the HTML element within by accessing `.nativeElement:

```
this.wrapperElRef.nativeElement //: HTMLDivElement
```

You can now do

```
this.wrapperElRef.nativeElement.append(elem)
```

---

That said, unless you know what you're doing (usually wrapping an existing library or integrating with an existing large system that you cannot yet refactor completely)

Comment: I think the first and last examples (manually calling `HTMLElement#append()`) should be avoided, since messing with the DOM outside of Angular's scope can cause misalignment between Angular's render tree and the actual DOM. Angular provides [`Renderer2`](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2), a built-in service which allows to to modify the DOM manually, while allowing Angular to keep track of the DOM. It has a function named [`appendChild`](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2#appendchild) which you can use.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times it depends how you have created the html.
I suggest specifying in comments where are you receiving the variable which holds the `HTMLElement`, so I could give you the most effective way to do it.

But generally -
try using `innerHTML` binding in the parent element.

**Typescript:**

```js
public elem: HTMLElement;

public getElement(): string {
   return this.elem.innerHTML;
}
```

**HTML:**

```html
<div innerHTML="getElement()"></div>
```

Comment: The element was created by a service, not in the component.

Comment: @IterAtor But how? What methods have you used? Did you took it from ElemntRef? (#id in othe component)?
Also, did my solution work?

Comment: No, it was created with `document.createElement`